# How to make Tortoise recognize project checkout originaly using Eclipse Plugin for SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin

On Windows 7, I have been using Tortoise for Subversion. I am also using Eclipse plugin for Subversion. I am using both of them interchangeably for making commits or updates to the project files. But on another system, I have same setup, Tortoise doesn't recognize the folders/files as SVN which are checked out using Eclipse.

I wonder, how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it does not recognize them as versioned or just does not display them with a TSVN icon? If you right-click on a folder does it show you the option to update it or to check-out into it? If it lets you update the folder it means that it recognizes it as versioned and the problem is only with an icon, which is not a big deal. If it shows the option to check out into it then the problem is deeper.

Comment: On one system it does, on another it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, this means that Eclipse did not really do the checkout, but rather export or something like that. I'll add [tag:eclipse] tag and convert my answer into a comment within couple of hours.

Comment: No. The only thing I can add is this: Tortoise expects .svn subfolder in every versioned folder of your working copy. If it's missing Tortoise won't recognize your working copy as vertioned. To correct this you can check that working copy out with `--force` option - you'll have to use the command line client, Tortoise does not support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experiences with Eclipse Subversion plugins (Subclipse, Subversive) and other clients (command line client, Tortoise, RapidSVN) ranges from "just work" to "destroyed workspaces". One time, a simple `svn info` on a Eclipse workspace changed all the meta data in a way, that Eclipse lost the project's connection to SVN.

The disk layout format depends on the connector type and its version.

Mabye the best bet is to use JavaHL as the plugin connector because it uses the same native libraries as Tortoise and the command line client.

Currently my personal policy is to use only one kind of SVN client for a workspace.

Comment: Can you please give some information on using JavaHL as the plugin connector for svn?

Comment: Go to Preferences / Team / SVN. There you can choose between different connectors like SVNKit and JavaHL. If there is no JavaHL option, then you have to use the Eclipse update mechanism to install the JavaHL connector. E.g. for Subversive you can look at http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive.php for the update site.

Comment: Ok, then you have to take care that JavaHL's subversion libraries match with Tortoise's libraries. In this list for every JavaHL version you can find the corresponding library version: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5ccce53a67ca6c3965de863ae91e2642eab537de

Answer (score 0):

More or less recently format of SVN working copy has changed. Could it be that Eclipse plugin and TortoiseSVN use different formats? The latest version of TortoiseSVN uses the new format, it may make sense to check this for Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your Eclipse plugin (are you using Subclipse? Subversive? another plugin?) and TortoiseSVN are based on the same version of Subversion. Any time Subversion release a new veresion (for example, from 1.5 to 1.6, or 1.6 to 1.7) they tend to modify the svn working copy format in such a way it's not recognized by SVN clients based on older versions.

For example, see the [1.6 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#wc-upgrades) for more information.