# Subversion flags folders as deleted on update

Tags: eclipse, svn

**EDIT:** Found that I at least can check out the project again and just replace the `.svn` folders. It's faster, but still tedious... Would like to know why this is happening.

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I'm having a pretty weird thing happening to me with subversion. I think it's Eclipse causing it (actually using SpringSsource Tool Suite 2.5.2.FINAL).

I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04` with svn version `1.6.17 (r1128011)`.

See behaviour below:

```
$ svn up
D    styleguide
D         integrator/war
D         portal/portlets
D         portal/theme
D         smsgateway/war
D         core/war
D         emailgateway/war
Updated to revision 14913.

$ ls core/    
jar  pom.xml  war

$ svn ls core
jar/
pom.xml
war/

$ cd core
$ svn status
?       war
?       jar/target
M       jar/src/main/resources/core/hessian-service.xml
?       jar/src/main/java/META-INF

$ svn ls war
svn: 'war' is not under version control

$ svn info
Path: .
URL: http://example.dev.local/svn/app/trunk/core
[omitted the rest]

$ svn co http://example.dev.local/svn/app/trunk/core testcore
$ cd testcore
$ ls
jar  pom.xml  war
```

So, the folder(s) got removed on the update and it's telling me they are not under version control. Sounds like something in the `.svn` folder got corrupted/removed. I'm thinking it's Eclipse causing it since that's the only thing ever touching these folders.

Is this a known issue (I've tried googling on it but found nothing), and is there a way to "repair" the `.svn` folder? I can solve this by removing the core folder and do another update, but it's tedious if I have files that I've not checked in, since I have to manually copy them to some temp folder and copy them back after I've restored the core folder again, and I also have to reimport the project in Eclipse since the project files have been removed...

This happens to me every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10470473/1178189) it's not a good idea to mix the Eclipse plugin with other clients.

As an aside: it **looks like** the files have been `svn deleted` so the update legitimately removes them from under version control (it does not delete them because there are some unversioned files there). But in that case checking out the project again wouldn't help. Run `svn log -v`  - maybe it will shed some light on what happened and who's done it.

Comment: The thing is, no one has done it. It happens every now and then. And If I check out the directory again (as shown in the output) everything is in place where it should be... I have not myself installed any svn-plugins to Eclipse, and I cannot find any in the "installed software" list, so I don't think I have that problem (I only use svn from the command line).